# Validating data in WPF textboxes before instantiating a C# object?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF browser application with a ListBox that contains information about a number of objects of the Bicycle class. The bottom half of the app contains a number of TextBoxes where users can enter information about a new Bicycle. My goal is to use validation rules (the ones that I have already work) to show validation errors if the user doesn't enter acceptable values in the fields and not allow the data to be submitted until all fields pass the validation test. My problem is that I am not sure how to validate the data if it is not bound to an instantiated Bicycle object. Should I create a constructor in the Bicycle class that accepts zero parameters and bind the TextBox values to this instance? Or is there some way to bind validation rules to properties of a class without creating an instance of that class? What would the source be?

Edit: When submitted, the Bicycle object with the user's TextBox inputs gets stored in an ObservableCollection, which populates the ListBox. If I use one instance of the Bicycle class to bind the data, I'm not sure how I can get the data from the TextBoxes to add multiple (unique) Bicycles to the ObservableCollection.

Edit: I bound the TextBoxes to a Bicycle object separate from the collection and passed the values from it into a new Bicycle object that could be added to the collection when the user pressed the submit button. I was unable to figure out how to copy a Bicycle object instead of just passing the original as a reference, but sending values into the constructor of a new Bicycle object might avoid problems like [this](http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm).

Comment: Just create a method will all your validation. Then before you process your data, call your validation class. If it passes then return true and if not, return false.

Comment: I would suggest you look at implementing the IDataErrorInfo interface on your Bicycle class (or create a BicycleViewModel and follow the MVVM pattern).  Then in your constructor you can set the intial errors on the "required" fields and the bindings should pick this up.  This is likely to take a bit of reworking though as it won't reuse the existing validation rules you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code-behind, create an instance of Bicycle.  Have a public property in your code behind that returns that Bicycle instance.  Then bind all of your text boxes to properties on the Bicycle.  ie:  Bicycle.TireSize, or Bicycle.Color, or whatever.  Then you can just validate the Bicycle object when the user is done entering their data.  If it's valid, your Bicycle is already built and you can send it to wherever you need to store it.

Comment: Is there any way to return the actual value of the Bicycle instead of the reference, so that if the user enters different values into the TextBoxes, they can make a new Bicycle that can be stored and the TextBox values won't still be bound to the content of the old Bicycle object?

Comment: What I do in that case is put a copy constructor on the Bicycle object.  Then, I set the Bicycle Editor's Bicycle object to a COPY of my original Bicycle.  That way, if we don't like the changes, the original isn't changed.  If we accept the changes, we set our original Bicycle to the Bicycle Editor's Bicycle, and the change is made.